# DAX Function to recreate Power Pivot view shown of Deltas between 2 scenarios

Tags: dax, powerquery, powerpivot

New to DAX and pushing calculations that are currently in Power Query into DAX to reduce query refresh time. I'm trying to recreate the below pivot view using DAX to calculate the deltas between two scenarios by several dimensions across time. In Power Query, I merge Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 into 2 columns, calculate the deltas in calculated columns, and then pivot the columns to get a "Deltas" scenario. I'm doing this across several metrics (pivot table shown is a simplified view for just one metric, units).

Pivot table "Show as Difference" function is messy and shows redundant blank rows. I am hoping to use DAX to calculate the deltas instead and display them in the same way in the pivot. All relationships are established correctly. !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZoCC.png)

I tried the following in DAX but did not get a similar result to the pivot..it only calculated the totals and the row level data was not correct

```
=CALCULATE(tblData[Units], tbleData[Scenario Name]=Scenario 1) 
-CALCULATE(tblData[Units], tbleData[Scenario Name]=Scenario 2)
```

Edit: added sample data below.

| Customer | Product | Scenario | Quarter | Units | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer A | Product A | Scenario 1 | CQ1-23 | 55 | $49.00 |
| Customer B | Product A | Scenario 1 | CQ1-23 | 81 | $77.00 |
| Customer C | Product B | Scenario 1 | CQ1-23 | 23 | $98.00 |
| Customer A | Product A | Scenario 1 | CQ2-23 | 98 | $62.00 |
| Customer B | Product A | Scenario 1 | CQ2-23 | 67 | $61.00 |
| Customer C | Product B | Scenario 1 | CQ2-23 | 78 | $8.00 |
| Customer A | Product A | Scenario 2 | CQ1-23 | 38 | $45.00 |
| Customer B | Product A | Scenario 2 | CQ1-23 | 73 | $79.00 |
| Customer C | Product B | Scenario 2 | CQ1-23 | 27 | $22.00 |
| Customer A | Product A | Scenario 2 | CQ2-23 | 79 | $90.00 |
| Customer B | Product A | Scenario 2 | CQ2-23 | 39 | $74.00 |
| Customer C | Product B | Scenario 2 | CQ2-23 | 5 | $79.00 |

Comment: You appear to have attached a picture, as opposed to copiable sample data with which to work and test potential solutions.

Comment: Added a sample data table

Comment: So that's the raw data? And what are the expected results?

Comment: This is a simplified view of the sample data. The real data has many more rows and measures that I am calculating deltas between Scenario 1 and 2 on. . I'm trying to create the deltas view in the Pivot Table shown in the image by leveraging DAX instead of my current solution which uses calculated columns in power query. The refresh time is quite long with my current solution.

Comment: Ah, ok. I was hoping for raw data plus expected results based on that raw data. Hope someone else picks up on this thread shortly for you.

Comment: Expected results are recreating this pivot in the image below using dax calculations for Deltas.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZoCC.png

Comment: @JosWoolley let me know what format/results you would need to see and I can modify. Appreciate the help.